# Is there any way to create 360 Video or 360 Image Player using Cardbord sdk?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I researched a lot but did not find the proper document or proper solution to build 2D 360 Video view or 360 Image View using CardBoard sdk.

Why CardBoardSdk? Because Google VR SDK is no more support so we can't use it for feature development.